# saveAll() works but throws an error

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm developing an app on iOS. I am updating my Users custom 'Rank' field based on their ordered 'Time01' field so they can be ordered on a scoreboard.

The code updates the 'Rank' fields but I get an error response.

This is my code...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateRanks", function(request, status) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.ascending('Time01');
    query.find({
        success: function(users) {
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { 
                users[i].set("Rank", i + 1);
            }
            Parse.Object.saveAll(users, {
                    useMasterKey: true,
                    success: function(result) {
                            response.success();
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                            response.error(error);
                    }
                });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the error I get...

```
2015-06-28 15:34:46.276 Juggs[1188:166690] [Error]: ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at Parse.Object.saveAll.success (main.js:205:24)
    at Parse.js:2:7765
    at e (Parse.js:2:6545)
    at Parse.js:2:5994
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:664)
    at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:5945)
    at e (Parse.js:2:6680)
    at Parse.js:2:5994
    at Array.forEach (native) (Code: 141, Version: 1.6.1)
```

I have called `response.success()` in the `saveAll` call so I'm wondering why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as the error message suggests: `response` is not defined.

The second parameter for `function` should be `response` as shown below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateRanks", function(request, response) {
    ...
}
```

Or you could use your existing `status` in place of `response`:

```
status.success()
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Sorry now that you've pointed that out it seems to obvious! Changed 'status' to 'response' and the error is gone :)